# i can't update Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have a macbook air and I went to the store to install Xcode 7.3 and hit the update App button, and a loading icon appeared but after waiting 30 min time nothing happened. I successfully installed simple recorder from the store but I can't install Xcode.

What can i do?

What are the options to download it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting your computer to see if Xcode has installed. This will also refresh the app store, so try downloading it again.

If all else fails:

You should uninstall all current versions of Xcode on your Mac. Do this by dragging each application to the Trash can. Delete your trash.

After, try downloading Xcode again and everything should go through.

You aren't aloud to download old versions of Xcode from the App Store.

Comment: Absolutely not. Torrented illegitimate Xcode is how iOS users get infected with malware (see "XcodeGhost"). Apple makes older dev tools freely available on their site: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: i refreshed a lot of times but nothing

Comment: Uninstall an application by dragging the app to the trash and emptying your trash.

Answer (score 2):

www.developer.apple.com -> Login -> Account -> Downloads

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to download the new [XCode 8](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). It works just fine, even if your update button doesn't seem to work. Need to use the App Store. Also, if you happen to be a React Native developer, you may want to follow [this article](https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/react-native-on-xcode-beta-8-0-how-to-fix-initial-build-error-f0225c649850#.afmaqg9uk) just after having installed this new XCode version.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply cannot install the latest version, I suggest going to www.developer.apple.com and click the Develop Tab, Xcode, Download, sign in with your apple id, and get an Xcode beta version.

Answer (score 1):

If only spinner is showing, without progress. Open Activity monitor and check if installd is running and using a lot of memory. Try killing that process and update again.